# Oracle Linux mailx configuration of carbon copy of root user - where?

Tags: linux, email

We have an Oracle Linux box running kernel 2.6.39.
We like to send mail on command line with this Linux box using root user.
When we tried

```
CC_LIST="ccc@xyz.com,ddd@xyz.com"
cat a.txt | mail -s "Test" "abc@xyz.com, asc@xyz.com" -c "${CC_LIST}"
```

When we receive the mail in our Outlook, the carbon copy users are not recognized because we have another user appended in the To: list.
In the To: list, it contains

```
abc@xyz.com; asc@xyz.com; -c@myhost.xyz.com; ccc@xyz.com; ddd@xyz.com
```

In the Cc: list, it is empty.

As you can see, "-c@myhost.xyz.com" messes up the command line.

Where is the mailx configuration file for program /bin/mail ?
/bin/mail is linked to mailx

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

use -c option with its receipients before "To" receipients list

Comment: It might be nice to know *why* this is necessary.

Comment: man mailx says so.

Comment: Are you able to provide a quote from the man page where it states? We like to have all the information needed in one place and a truly complete answer tends to elicit more upvotes.

Comment: Usage: mailx -eiIUdEFntBDNHRV~ -T FILE -u USER -h hops -r address -s SUBJECT -a FILE -q FILE -f FILE -A ACCOUNT -b USERS **-c USERS** -S OPTION users